# How to have an instance delete itself from within a prototype function is JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have a JavaScript constructor function, and I set a destroy method on its prototype. Is it possible to delete (or at least unset) the instance from the destroy method? Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
Klass.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    // do stuff
  },
  destroy: function() {
    // delete the instance    
  }
};

k = new Klass
k.destroy()
console.log(k) // I want this to be undefined
```

I understand that I can't simply do `this = undefined` from with the destroy method, but I thought I could get around that by using a timeout like so:

```
destroy: function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout( function() {
    self = undefined
  }, 0)  
}
```

I thought the timeout function would have access to the instance via `self` from the closure (and it does), but that doesn't seem to work. If I `console.log(self)` from inside that function it shows up as `undefined`, but `k` in the global scope is still an instance of `Klass`.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: may I ask you why you need to `destroy` an instance like this? answering the question you asked is one thing but it may not help you do what you are trying to do hence my question

Comment: JavaScript is garbage collected and has no explict way to destroy an object so there is no built in language way to do what you are asking. As with Pavel, I am very curious as to why you need such a thing, there is probably a better way to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: It's for a jQuery plugin. Having a destroy method seems more intuitive then expecting devs to delete or unset their own instances, but perhaps it's not.

Comment: Sounds like you are carrying sensibilities from a previous life. In JavaScript you remove the reference and the let the garbage collector sort it out. There are special cases around older DOM implementation but if the reference isn't in the DOM you don't need a special `destroy` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`k` is a reference that points out to an instance of `Klass`. when you call `destroy` as a method of `Klass` the `this` inside the function gets bound to the object you called a `destroy` method on. It now is another reference to that instance of `Klass`. The `self` that you close on in that little closure is yet another reference to that instance. When you set it to `undefined` you clear that reference, not the instance behind it. You can't really `destroy` that instance per se. You can *forget* about it (set all the references to `undefined` and you won't find it again) but that is as far as you can go.

That said, tell us what you want to accomplish with this and we'll be glad to help you find a solution.

Comment: You're right, I always forget that assigning `self = this` only holds a reference to where `this` is in memory. Obviously it doesn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Though deleting its own object instance is possible, it is very tacky. You might want to check out [this](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) article.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Even if you overwrite `this` it will not affect any variable holding a reference to that instance. And calling a function on it will still have the correct `this`.

The only thing you could do is setting a variable in your `destroy` function that will make any other function throw an exception when called. But that would be a bad idea since it would slow things down (ok, that's negligible) and you can just put in the docs of your class that it is not supposed to be used anymore after `destroy()` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it requires that you know what the name of variable to which the `new Klass()` is instantiated:

```
function Klass() {};

Klass.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    //
  },
  destroy: function() {
    // Delete the variable that references the instance of the constructor.
    delete window.k;
  }
};

k = new Klass();
k.destroy();
console.log(k);
```

If the `k` variable is named anything else it doesn't work:

```
// Won't work.
u = new Klass();
u.destroy();
```

It also assumes that the local variable `k` is really in the global scope.  If it were inside a function it would not work either.  For instance:

```
// Won't work.
var fn = function() {
  k = new Klass();
  k.destroy();
};
```

Finally it assumes a browser environment for the `window` object.

Comment: Or you could pass the name of the var through a parameter `destroy(ref);` and eval the code if necessary.

Comment: what if I had `a = k` right before the `k.destroy()`? I would assume the `a` will still be there referencing that instance

Comment: @PavelVeller that is exactly right.  I am not proposing that this is a robust solution at all.

Comment: @NoahFreitas right, just wanted to make it clear that your code deletes a property from another object that happens to be a reference to the instance that the author of the question wanted destroyed

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me in my situation