# JavaScript: Create and destroy class instance through class method

Tags: javascript, class, object

I'm trying to figure out how to delete an object through a class method. I would like to be able to create a class that has a destroy method that releases the object from memory. So far, the research I've done has been inconclusive. I understand that garbage collection will eventually take care of the object, but I'd like a more definitive way to destroy it. Is this possible?

```
// class constructor
var class = function () {
     this.destroy = function () {};
};

// instance
var instance = new class();
instance.destroy();
console.log(instance); // should be null or undefined
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have an instance delete itself from within a prototype function is JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826046/how-to-have-an-instance-delete-itself-from-within-a-prototype-function-is-javasc)

Comment: This kind of question seems to come from a misunderstanding of how instances of objects live and die. This is not how JS works at all, but that doesn't mean it's a limitation.  It means things need to be done a different way. So what is your real goal here?

Comment: My goal is to quickly delete the object including event handlers and anything that was created as a result of the object being created. @NickC

Comment: check my answer out, I think you would get all you want out of it.

Comment: I am not a frequenter of SO, so came across this late. Often I see people trying to scope the class, but loading it into the document with document.head.appendChild(). This will register, and the eval() - even if eval.call({},js) will use the window scope to find the class.
Instead do not add it to the document (if you are), rather eval the entire class with something like eval.call({},'class myclass{} (function(){ return new MyClass()})()'). 
This shouldn't use the window and you can replace the MyClass at anytime.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. JavaScript is automatically garbage collected; the object's memory will be reclaimed only if the GC decides to run and the object is eligible for collection.

Seeing as that will happen automatically as required, what would be the purpose of reclaiming the memory explicitly?

Comment: I would like to quickly remove event handlers, references, etc. that were created when the object was created.

Comment: @user699242: Again, why? If noone but the object has a reference to this stuff then reclaiming the object will also allow reclaiming the stuff. You don't need to do anything other than "lose" all references to the object. Why do you want to do it manually?

Comment: I guess 'loosing all references' to the object is ambiguous to me. When does that happen? Sorry, this has always confused me

Comment: In other words, do I need to do anything to 'loose the references'. For example setting the pointer to null or...

Comment: There are too many possibilities to enumerate, but in general "setting that thing to `null`" will work. However this is something you should get a better handle on, as it can make the difference between leaking memory all the way to crashtown or not. You 'd really have to *try* to leak like that, but...

Comment: @Jon do you know if i can bind a callback function on that automatic collecting? (gets run when instance is destroyed)

Comment: @philx_x: You can't, the concept does not exist. It's also unclear what you would be trying to achieve.

Comment: @jon allright, thanks for clarification. i don't wan't to achieve something it was just out of curiosity so i could maybe log when instances get collected.

Answer (score 69):

1- There is no way to actually destroy an object in javascript, but using `delete`, we could remove a reference from an object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.mypointer = null;
delete obj.mypointer;
```

2- The important point about the `delete` keyword is that it does not actually destroy the object BUT if only after deleting that reference to the object, there is no other reference left in the memory pointed to the same object, that object would be marked as collectible. The `delete` keyword deletes the reference but doesn't GC the actual object. it means if you have several references of the same object, the object will be collected just after you delete all the pointed references.

3- there are also some tricks and workarounds that could help us out, when we want to make sure we do not leave any memory leaks behind. for instance if you have an array consisting several objects, without any other pointed reference to those objects, if you recreate the array all those objects would be killed. For instance if you have `var array = [{}, {}]` overriding the value of the array like `array = []` would remove the references to the two objects inside the array and those two objects would be marked as collectible.

4- for your solution the easiest way is just this:

```
var storage = {};
storage.instance = new Class();
//since 'storage.instance' is your only reference to the object, whenever you wanted to destroy do this:
storage.instance = null;
// OR
delete storage.instance;
```

As mentioned above, either setting `storage.instance = null` or `delete storage.instance` would suffice to remove the reference to the object and allow it to be cleaned up by the GC. The difference is that if you set it to `null` then the storage object still has a property called instance (with the value null). If you `delete storage.instance` then the storage object no longer has a property named instance.

and **WHAT ABOUT destroy method ??**

the paradoxical point here is if you use `instance.destroy` in the destroy function you have no access to the actual `instance` pointer, and it won't let you delete it.

The only way is to pass the reference to the destroy function and then delete it:

```
// Class constructor
var Class = function () {
     this.destroy = function (baseObject, refName) {
         delete baseObject[refName];
     };
};

// instanciate
var storage = {};
storage.instance = new Class();
storage.instance.destroy(object, "instance");
console.log(storage.instance); // now it is undefined
```

**BUT** if I were you I would simply stick to the first solution and delete the object like this:

```
storage.instance = null;
// OR
delete storage.instance;
```

WOW it was too much :)

Comment: @vsync If it isn't attached to any object or variable, then it will be collected once it has finished running any code. For example, if you do `(new SomeObject).doSomething)`, then it will be collected after it is done executing `doSomething`. If the object has a `setTimeout` call or anything else that fires async logic, then SomeObject won't be collected until those other tasks are done (unless those tasks don't contains references to the SomeObject instance or anything else belonging to the SomeObject instance).

Comment: @vsync Suppose the `doSomething` method goes and sets a `setInterval` that does `console.log(this)`, then the setInterval will run forever and the SomeObject will never be collected, unless the interval has code that will `clearInterval` at some point. Basically, if there's no code to run (or being ran) by an object, and no references to it, it will be collected.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The [delete keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description) in javascript removes a property from an object. It does not directly free memory, nor destroy an object. And if it did, it would make no sense to set the reference to null prior to calling `delete`.

Comment: @DavidMills Thank you for letting me know I had this incorrect answer from years ago, I made some changes, would u please review to make sure if it makes sense now?

Comment: In the `storage.instance` example, if you want to allow the GC to clean up the `instance` object, then _either_ setting `storage.instance = null` *or* `delete storage.instance` would suffice to remove the reference to the object and allow it to be cleaned up by the GC. The difference is that if you set it to `null` then the `storage` object still has a property called `instance` (with the value `null`). If you `delete storage.instance` then the `storage` object no longer has a property named `instance`.

Comment: @DavidMills Thanks for the reply, I added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can only manually delete properties of objects. Thus:

```
var container = {};

container.instance = new class();

delete container.instance;
```

However, this won't work on any other pointers. Therefore:

```
var container = {};

container.instance = new class();

var pointer = container.instance;

delete pointer; // false ( ie attempt to delete failed )
```

Furthermore:

```
delete container.instance; // true ( ie attempt to delete succeeded, but... )

pointer; // class { destroy: function(){} }
```

So in practice, deletion is only useful for removing object properties themselves, and is not a reliable method for removing the code they point to from memory.

A manually specified `destroy` method could unbind any event listeners. Something like:

```
function class(){
  this.properties = { /**/ }

  function handler(){ /**/ }

  something.addEventListener( 'event', handler, false );

  this.destroy = function(){
    something.removeEventListener( 'event', handler );
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this = void 0; an invalid left hand assignment?

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's also a really stupid idea, since all it could do even if it did work is cause errors due to missing pointers.