# Control Active Constructors Based on Index

Tags: javascript, constructor

I want to be able to control constructors with their id (location in array) I am not sure if it is possible to kill a single constructor's process but that is what i am looking for. I need to be able to stop and start constructors with their index in the list.

```
class Worker {
  constructor(id, fname, lname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.age = age;
  }
  if (this.id===1) {
    process.exit()
  } else {
    console.log(fname+" "+lname+" "+age);
  }
}

let fnames = ["johnathan", "richard", "david", "hayden", "josh", "harry", "raymond", "braylon", "john", "kent"];
let lnames = ["smith", "scott", "richards", "stine", "davidson", "dominic", "weltz", "joseph", "daigle", "goodman"];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let worker = new Worker(i, fnames[i], lnames[i]);
  workers.push(worker);
}
```

Comment: A constructor is not a process that could be killed from outside. It just initialises an instance and then returns it, and before that nothing else will happen. So what exactly are you expecting to "start and stop"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what you mean by "kill a constructor's process."  JavaScript is a garbage-collected language, so the runtime takes care of removing object instances for you when there is no longer a reference to them.

See this post which, while not a duplicate of yours, is similar: [JavaScript: Create and destroy class instance through class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118952/javascript-create-and-destroy-class-instance-through-class-method)

However, if you wanted to trigger some method call on the instance based on its `id` value at construction, you could do that like this:

```
class Worker {
  constructor(id, fname, lname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.age = age;
    if (this.id===1) {
      this.someMethod();
    } else {
      console.log(fname+" "+lname+" "+age);
    }
  }

  someMethod(){
    // do the thing here
  }

}
```